# How can i specify folder for bpmn processes?

Tags: spring, camunda, bpmn

My problem is that default directory for bpmn processes is **resources**.
But i need to store them in the root of project in special directory.
How can i specify it?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in adding string in application.properties like this :

```
camunda.bpm.deployment-resource-pattern[]= file:./{name of your folder in root}/*
```

That`s all.